# В Tkinter как заставить кнопку менять цвет при нажатии?

Tags: python, tkinter

Вроде бы, для этого требуется всего лишь указать параметр activebackground, однако при его добавлении кнопка хотя и функционально работает, но статична.

Второй вопрос. Я пишу программу магического шара, которая при заданном ей вопросе отдает случайный ответ из имеющегося в ее списке. Сейчас функция ответа шара привязана к кнопке "Спросить". И так выходит, что обработчик события реагирует даже на пустое поле без заданного в нем вопроса. Как указать программе не отвечать (или отвечать чем-то вроде "Задайте вопрос"), если поле с вопросом пусто?

```
# кнопка для ввода вопроса в программу
button_ask = tk.Button(
    master=frame_question_answer,
    text='Спросить',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='red'  # почему-то цвет при нажатии на красный не меняется
)

button_ask.grid(
    row=3, column=0, sticky='e'
)

# Обработчик вопроса пользователя 
def questionQuery():
    question = text_box_question.get('1.0', tk.END) # читаем текст из виджета text_box_question
    time.sleep(2)

# Функция возврата случайных ответов
def answerQuery():
    text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Хмм...' + '\n') # и выводим в виджет text_box_answer
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(2)
    text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Я заглядываю за повороты судьбы, чтобы узнать о грядущем' + '\n')
    window.update_idletasks()
    window.after(2000, lambda: text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, random.choice(responses) + '\n'))

def call_funcs(event):
    questionQuery()
    answerQuery()

# привязываем к кнопке обработку события
button_ask.bind('<Button>', call_funcs)
```

Comment: @Интик, винда )

Comment: И кстати иногда, как сейчас вижу, параметр работает. Однако делает это через раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам портит "всю малину" функция `sleep()`, которая на время ожидания блокирует любую перерисовку. А так как из-за `button_ask.bind('<Button>', call_funcs)` функция позовётся при нажатии кнопки мыши, а не при отпускании, как по идее правильнее будет - у кнопки почти не остаётся шанса поменять свой цвет.

Альтернативы, как я вижу, такие:

1. Вешать обработчик нажатия напрямую на кнопку, а не через `bind()`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

def questionQuery():
    root.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(2)
    btn.configure(text='Done')

root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, activebackground='red', text="Press me", command=questionQuery)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

2. Или использовать отложенное исполнение части функции при помощи метода `after()` и никогда не использовать `sleep()` в UI.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

def questionQuery_After():
    btn.configure(text='Done')

def questionQuery(event):
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.after(2000, questionQuery_After)

root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, activebackground='red', text="Press me")
btn.pack()
btn.bind('<Button>', questionQuery)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: дельные рекомендации, опробовал оба варианта, но результат пока тот же, к сожалению. Опять же есть функция со слипом, но кнопка там меняет состояние - цвет при нажатии становится иным

Comment: @АлексейКазанцев Странно. У меня на Win7 прекрасно раскрашивается. Пробовали мои примеры, или уже в вашей программе аналогичное не работает?

Comment: заметил, что кнопка перестает "нажиматься", когда привязываешь к ней функцию. До привязки - работает как надо

Comment: продолжаю эксперименты: вычистил все от sleep - кнопка заработала, как надо. Но... теперь несмотря на использованный метод window.after(2000, lambda:...) нет 2-секундной задержки

Answer (score 0):

Побуду немного археологом, но столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Удаление слипов так же не помогло. Помогло наоборот реакцию на нажатие сделать не через command=...., а через bind. И заработало как надо, даже со sleep